# Openconnect with IPsec protocol

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec

I need to force openconnect to use IPsec protocol as first option. As long as I know, openconnect first try SSL connection (correct me if I am wrong). Problem is, that our company ASA deny my connection when I try other than IPse connection. In Windows in anyconnect I can fix it in xml profile but I didnt find any way in openconnect. I tried to use

```
# openconnect --xmlconfig Profile.xml
```

where Profile.xml is my correct profile that I use in anyconnect, but it didn't work. I use Fedora OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, OpenConnect is a CSTP-only client and does not support IPsec for Cisco VPNs – neither the new IKEv2 variant, nor the traditional "Cisco IPSec". You'll need to use `vpnc` for the older VPN protocol.

Comment: Thank you for yout answer. I will probably move back to anyconnect on Linux too.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ubuntu 

sudo apt install vpnc

limix@mxli:/usr/local/bin$ sudo vpnc-connect 
Enter IPSec gateway address: demo.ipsec.com
Enter IPSec ID for demo.ipsec.com: sharekey
Enter IPSec secret for  sharekey@demo.ipsec.com: 
Enter username for demo.ipsec.com: limix
Enter password for limix@demo.ipsec.com: 
VPNC started in background (pid: 17780)...
```

vpnc work fine for me